# HTML website programming

Tags: html

I am starting a new business and am creating a basic website for displaying what it is about and its products.
I have started with an outline in HTML and CSS, but I have met on some trouble with adding submitting forms and adding a path to the links.

I have figured out how to make a basic form like this:

```
 <form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <br>
  E-mail:<br>
  <input type="text" name=„E-mail“>
</form>
```

But whenever I click the submit button the page gets an error and I am also not sure where the data would be stored. I have not yet set up the domain for the website so I am still doing this in my browser.

Also if I want to have a link to another page on my website such as:

```
<a href="#">Learn More</a>
```

how do I add the path to the next page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I were you, I would buy a commercial template or hire (if you can afford) a professional to do the website for your business. Best of luck :)

Comment: Thanks :) I am almost done with the website format, I just need to figure out how to add the information forms and maybe a calculator later and I think that should be manageable :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to learn first how html works, and how to receive data with a server-side language (like php, java, asp, nodejs, etc).

To put a target to the form make something like this:

```
  <form action="your-target-page.php" method="POST">
```

If you have a php server you can receive data:

```
   $email = $_POST['email']
```

Learn more about form tag:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/form

Comment: Alright thanks. So I guess the website domain I will buy would function as a server for my website? or do I have to setup a server myself?

Comment: You can buy a shared hosting (20€ / year or less in esquio.net) and it runs 24/7/365, or you can mount a Webserver in your machine and let it run all time you need (if you turn off computer, your site will be innaccesible)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the form you are going to need a server side language to handle the posting of a form. If you are new to website creation I would suggest using Wordpress and an already made free theme.

For your form this is better markup:

```
<form>
  <label>First name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <label>E-mail:</label>
  <input type="text" name="email">
</form>
```

Assuming you have a file called learn_more.html in the same root that is how the link would work, target="_blank" opens it in a new browser window, if you just want it in the same window omit this.

```
<a href="learn_more.html" target="_blank">Learn More</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! Well, I am quite new to HTML but have experience with java and python so I would like to make the site myself.

Answer (score 0):

HTML form doesn't store any data with itself. It can just **send** a formed data to a server **via HTTP protocol**.

You need to have any kind of server side (CGI) program. Those are usually programmed in Perl, Python, Ruby, Java, PHP or so on.

In short

1. Send data to server side program from HTML form
2. Receive and process data with the program.

Comment: You make it sound like CGI is a must, which — of course — it isn't.